# Separated axis in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, distance, axis

I would like to plot a scatterplot + rectangles/lines with ggplot, and besides including axis/ticks in the sides, something like [that histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTmnB.png). In summary, the plot could be quite similar to tufte theme, but even with that, I couldn't separate a certain distance the axis lines from the plot.

Is it possible? I would appreciate any help in this sense.

Comment: Distance to the axis is controlled by the `expand` parameter in the `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` functions. Or just change the x and y limits of the plot.

Comment: The histogram you link doesn't include a scatterplot. When you say "rectangles/lines" do you mean a histogram? Do you want a scatterplot with a histogram over plotted?

Comment: Hi Axeman, thank you very much for your help.I have not yet checked if expand is ok for it. Nevertheless, I don't want to change the x and y limits, The minimum value in both cases should be 0. Just as it is shown in the histogram, this doesn't mean the axis to share a vertex (0,0).

Comment: Dear Michelle, yes, I am aware the plot is a histogram. No, what I mean are boxes or lines but not bars from a histogram. I want to plot a scatter plot, but I will include rectangles for a certain reason (not a legend). And not, I don't want to plot simultaneously a scatterplot and histogram. In fact, the example of the histogram is just  because of the axes lines, which are not attached to the bars, but separated a certain distance